# Exception raised during rendering: / by zero Exception

Tags: android, xml

I am working on android application, in which i am getting an error of Zero Exception. I am also not able to see my xml display on editor but it is working on device or emulator. Kindly please guide me what should i do for this error. My XML code is given below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.zhy.view.CircleMenuLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_menulayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_bg" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_circle_menu_item_center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="104.0dip"
                android:layout_height="104.0dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/turnplate_center_unlogin" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="116.0dip"
                android:layout_height="116.0dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/turnplate_mask_unlogin_normal" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.zhy.view.CircleMenuLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: probably `104.0dip` causing issue try it as `104dip`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thanks for your reply. I just remove it, but still it is giving me the same error.

Comment: @U Khan: i hope you are using everywhere `dip` instead of `.0dip` . after that try to clear project and close and open layout file